# There are elements in $\mathbb Z [t]$ such that this sum is 1

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

In order to solve a problem I'm facing I want to prove that there are $f_1,f_2,f_3$ elements in $\mathbb Z[t]$ such that $f_1(t)\cdot(4t-4)+f_2(t)\cdot(5t)+f_3(t)\cdot(t^2-17)=1$. In another words, I would like to show this $(4t-4,5t,t^2-17)$ is an unimodular row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Am I right in thinking you want $f_1,f_2,f_3$ to be non-constant, i.e. $f_1,f_2,f_3\not\in\mathbb{Z}$? Otherwise $f_1=f_2=1$, $f_3=-1$ or anything similar seems to satisfy the required relation.

Comment: @HSN, how $\;f_1=f_2=1\;,\;\;f_3=-1\;$ satisfy the wanted relation??

Comment: It does not satisfy it, certainly $-t^2$ will survive.

Comment: @HSN the $f_i$'s can be constant, the problem is your $f_i$ doesn't satisfy the relation.

Comment: O, it is supposed to mean products? With this notation, I read it as substituting, for instance, $4t-4$ for $t$ in $f_1$. Using \cdot inbetween would've removed this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution. Take $f_1(t)=4t+4$, $f_2(t)=-3t$ and $f_3(t)=-1$. Then
$f_1\cdot(4t-4)+f_2\cdot (5t)+f_3\cdot (t^2-17)=1$.

Comment: how did you get the solution? was it by trial and error or do you have any particular method?

Comment: I made an "ansatz" with monic polynomials of low degree; similar questions arise from computations for the special linear group $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[t])$.

Comment: @user75086 No trial and error is needed, one can use a method similar to the extended euclidean algorithm - see my answer. More generally, look-up Hermite/Smith normal forms.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ The ideal contains $\,p_2\!-p_1 =\, t\!+\!4,\,$ so it contains $\ {-}p_3\ {\rm mod}\,\ t\!+\!4\, =\, -p_3(-4) = 1.\ \ $ **QED**